# Android libgdx enemies movement with respawn

Tags: android, libgdx, sprite

Im making a 2d game and I want enemies go right to the left and when one enemy goes out of the screen (on the left), instantly appears at the beggining again (on the right). How can I do this?

I can do the movement with addAction without a problem, but I have no idea about the "respawn" thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit hard to help you without any code example from your game. Assuming that you have something in your action that alters the position like

```java
x = x - pixelPerSecond * deltaTime;
```

then why not just adding some condition like

```java
if (x <= treshold) {
  x = startX;
} else {  
  x = x - pixelPerSecond * deltaTime;
}
```

Edit: Just edited "+" to "-" because you said "from right to left". But idea is the same.